# Resolve a hostname to ip address from host file C

Tags: c, network-programming

I am working on grid cluster interconnected. all the host to ip address mapping are in the /etc/host file.
my question is how can i get the ip by the hostname in my C code.
I can directly ssh compute-0-4.local . but how can i get its ip in my C code?

Comment: Doesn't the standard `gethostbyname` work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`getaddrinfo()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getaddrinfo) function to do a name look-up.